# Removing sessionId generation in JBoss AS7.1.1

Tags: jboss7.x

I have multi layered architecture (web <--> application service <--> data service) with multiple servers and the user sessionId is generated from a different server (data service). So I want to remove the default sessionId generation in JBoss.

How I can configure this? So that the HTTP response will not contain jsessionId.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Session id* is generated every time when session is created. So if You need sessions in Your application, You will need *session id* too. What You can do is to force parts of Your application to operate without session requirement.

**For example:** Your 'application service' can be a separate application, which will communicate with 'web' part of Your application using restfull web services. In such a situation 'application service' can operate without sessions. So the session id will not be generated.

Comment: in applicationservice it is fine. But in web.war the sessionId is generated. How I can disable that?

Comment: So You should investigate how Spring handles Http sessions and try to force Spring framework to not create sessions. Maybe these links will be helpfull: [session Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html), [Link-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176853/how-to-stop-spring-security-from-creating-a-new-session)

Comment: Your link helped to resolve. Not creating session at JSP level, worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [create-session="stateless"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http-create-session) option for spring security config