# invalidate session if user opens multiple tabs

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my project, I want to invalidate the user session and redirect the user to logout page if the user is trying to open a window's url on another tab in the same browser. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662431/how-to-stop-browsers-from-sharing-session-amongst-tabs

Comment: Use `window.name` to detect new tab in javascript

Comment: This will only lead to a bad user experience.

Comment: is there any tags that can be added to configuration file to disable session persistence in multiple tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML 5 local storage to count the number of open instances. Or simply use cookies to keep track of open instances.