# Spring MVC session gets refreshed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, spring-security, tomcat7

I'm developing an application using `Spring MVC` and I am facing some unexpected behavior while monitoring the `http session` object. While constantly posting to the server from multiple tabs in the same browser window I noticed that once in a while the session object gets refreshed (new object with new hashcode with empty attributes, but isNew method returns "false" as expected). We are using `Spring Security` but we did not configure session management.

I'm monitoring this behavior in a servlet filter.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: Have you gone through this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176853/how-to-stop-spring-security-from-creating-a-new-session.

Comment: Is session attributes are not empty then it is very much possible, you are seeing what @Harshakj89 has pointed. However, you say that the attributes are empty. What are posting to the server? Are all the requests that you make the same? Does any part of your code invalidate your session? Final Q: Does it always reset on the exact same number of requests? If the answer is yes for final Q, then it could be a security or other configuration that could be causing the issue.