# How to prevent HTTP session flood attack

Tags: spring, security, session, cookies, spring-security

**Flood Attack:**
In short, a hacker can keep hitting the server (without cookie) to force Java container to keep creating new session.

I am using Spring Security to manage session. I realize `jsessionid` keep being created before login, this is not what I want.

So I did:

1) in Spring security config:

```
sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
```

2) disable session creation in jsp. Because I am using apache tile, due to it is using dynamic include, so I have to disable session creation in all the jsp fragment. This is very tedious.

```
<%@page session="false"%>
```

First glance, it is fine, but there is a scenario I still got the session created.

Let's say before login, I visit a url that only can be visited after authenticated, Spring will redirect me to login page.

Before I am redirected, the response already instruct to set a new cookie, a session already created.

My Question:

1) Is session flood attack a serious issue? Should I really take care of it?

2) Is there any better way to handle this issue? Any best practise?

3) What happen to my code? It should work actually, I suspect the cookie is created by Spring, although I already set it to `SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER`. I can't set it to `Stateless`, I still need the session after login.

I am more concerned session attack compare to DDOS actually, I have also set `.maximumSessions(1)` in Spring to prevent multiple login. But above issue happen before login. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The first think I may suggest is a control like this one: if several requests arrive from the same IP address in short time (10 request in 10 seconds for example) block the request

Comment: I agree with @AngeloImmediata. If your objective is to prevent session flood attack which is 'a kind' of DDoS attack, take measures at the lower level to prevent such things to happen rather than your application server bother with it. By lower level, I mean use Firewall. Here is how you can do this using `iptables` : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/limit-max-connections-per-ip-address-and-new-connections-per-second-with-iptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point looks valid, it probably can be a serious issue if not handled. I found there is already an open issue on this topic. But there is a work around available to control this behavior.

```
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        public HttpSessionRequestCache getHttpSessionRequestCache() {
            HttpSessionRequestCache httpSessionRequestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
            httpSessionRequestCache.setCreateSessionAllowed(false);
            return httpSessionRequestCache;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestCache().requestCache(getHttpSessionRequestCache());
}
```

Refer following links for more details.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4242

[How to stop Spring Security from creating a new session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176853/how-to-stop-spring-security-from-creating-a-new-session)